# Custom Message on Arduino

Tags: arduino, ros-indigo, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS Indigo and an Arduino Uno. I am having issues using a custom message that is part of my firmware. The firmware compiles and uploads fine, but I receive the following error when trying to connect to the node.

```
$ rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM1
[INFO] [WallTime: 1448735717.440960] ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [WallTime: 1448735717.454322] Connecting to /dev/ttyACM1 at 57600 baud
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1448735720.172786] Creation of publisher failed: ros_arduino_wiichuck
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1448735721.135189] Tried to publish before configured, topic id 125
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1448735722.154916] Tried to publish before configured, topic id 125
```

Here is my custom message

```
Header header
uint8 joyX
uint8 joyY
bool buttonZ
bool buttonC
float32 accelX
float32 accelY
float32 accelZ
```

Here is my firmware code

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ros.h>
#include <ros_arduino_wiichuck/WiiChuck.h>


#include "WiiChuck.h"

WiiChuck chuck = WiiChuck();

ros::NodeHandle nh;

ros_arduino_wiichuck::WiiChuck chuck_msg;
ros::Publisher chuckPub("chuck", &chuck_msg);

char hello[13] = "hello world!";

void setup() {
    nh.initNode();
    nh.advertise(chuckPub);

    chuck.begin();
    chuck.update();
}

void loop() {
    delay(20);
    chuck.update();

    chuck_msg.joyX = chuck.readJoyX();
    chuck_msg.joyY = chuck.readJoyY();
    chuck_msg.buttonZ = chuck.buttonZ;
    chuck_msg.buttonC = chuck.buttonC;
    chuck_msg.accelX = chuck.readAccelX();
    chuck_msg.accelY = chuck.readAccelY();
    chuck_msg.accelZ = chuck.readAccelZ();
    chuckPub.publish(&chuck_msg);
    nh.spinOnce();
    delay(1000);
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221678/custom-message-on-arduino/) by [Noldona](https://answers.ros.org/users/25195/noldona/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**EDITED** to be correct answer.

You ROS path only includes directories in /opt ; have you sourced the workspace that contains your custom message before starting the rosserial_python node?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Noldona](https://answers.ros.org/users/25195/noldona/) on 2015-11-28**:
I thought the advertise line was the one that registered the publisher. Also, I started with the code used in http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello%20World and it works perfectly fine. The issue seems to be related to the fact that it's a custom message.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-11-28**:
You ROS path only includes directories in /opt ; have you sourced the workspace that contains your custom message before starting the rosserial_python node?

**Comment by [Noldona](https://answers.ros.org/users/25195/noldona/) on 2015-11-28**:
Yeah, that was it. I didn't source the workspace.

**Comment by [Copk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25313/copk/) on 2015-12-12**:
Can you guys also help me with this problem? I described it in an answer below (I am new at the forum, and don't know whether I whould ask it as a new question)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-12-12**:
You have a new, different question. Please ask a new question instead of posting an answer.